# How do I make a simple d3 chart with Firebase data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firebase, nvd3.js, angularfire

I'm trying to query how many entries a specific song has been recorded in firebase. In other words, I'm trying to get the total play count of the songs and plot them on a graph.

I'm tried to get the length of the firebase array but I know I have to use $loaded.then(function()). How would I use it here? My controller:

```
(function () {
function MetricsCtrl($scope,$firebaseArray, Metric) {
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://bloc-jams.firebaseio.com/");

    $scope.options = {...};

    var blue = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef.child('Songs').orderByChild('name').equalTo("Blue"))
    var green = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef.child('Songs').orderByChild('name').equalTo("Green"))
    var red = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef.child('Songs').orderByChild('name').equalTo("Red"))
    var pink = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef.child('Songs').orderByChild('name').equalTo("Pink"))
    var magenta = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef.child('Songs').orderByChild('name').equalTo("Magenta"))

    $scope.data = [
        {
            values: [
                {
                    "label" : "Blue" ,
                    "value" :  blue.length
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "Green" ,
                    "value" : green.length
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "Red" ,
                    "value" : red.length
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "Pink" ,
                    "value" : pink.length
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "Magenta" ,
                    "value" : magenta.length
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

angular
    .module('blocJams')
    .controller('MetricsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray','Metric', MetricsCtrl]);
})();
```

Comment: Any reason you're querying each of these individually, as an array? It looks like `$firebaseObject(firebaseRef.child('Songs'))` would be more straightforward. Also, for scalability, you'd probably want to compile the stats separately, ahead of time, so that getting the song count doesn't actually require loading every song in the database. Work hard on writes to make reads easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in reasoning that you can only make the chart after the firebase array is loaded.

If you're using angular's promise service $q:

```
$q.all([ blue.$loaded(), 
         green.$loaded(), 
         red.$loaded(), 
         pink.$loaded(), 
         magenta.$loaded()
]).then(makeChart)

function makeChart(data) {
  // data[0] is blue, data[1] is green, etc.
  // ...
  // $scope.data = [{...}]
}
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to load the data in a service, and have that service resolve in the router, so the controller doesn't need this coupling to do it's work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683882/start-svg-animation-after-scope-is-set-angularjs-svg/34686689#34686689) and [this doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes)